# How to transmit small UIImages over network with minimal loss in quality?

Tags: ios, uiimage

I need to send a UIImage over the Internet, but I've been having some issues so far.

I currently take the UIImage, make it a 16th the dimensions, convert it to NSData, and then create an NSString using NSData+base64. I then transmit this as part of a JSON request to a server.

Most of the time, this works perfectly.

However, the file sizes are large. On a cellular connection, an image can take ~10 seconds to load.

How do I transmit a UIImage, over the network, so that it's small and retains quality? Even when I make it a 16th of the previous number of pixels, a photograph can be 1.5MB. I'd like to get it around 300KB.

Compressing it with zip or gzip only seems to result in negligible (<.1MB) savings.

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Send the raw data instead of a base64 encoded string. That will take up much less bandwidth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest storing it as a JPEG or a PNG with some compression, Use a method like

```
        UIImageJPEGRepresentation(UIImage *image, CGFloat compressionQuality)
```

Then post the NSData object you get from that. You should be able to find a good ssize/quality tradeoff by playing with the compressionQuality variable.

Comment: Jpeg will help dramatically.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say how you are converting your images to data.  You mention “photograph”.  If your images are photographs, you should use [`UIImageJPEGRepresentation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation), not `UIImagePNGRepresentation`.  You will have to play with the `compressionQuality` parameter to find a compression level that balances data size and image quality.